# Simplifying $\ln{U}=-2\sin x+\ln{\cos x}+\ln{C}$ to find $U$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to simplify this expression and find my $U$. What should I do?
$$\ln{U}=-2\sin x+\ln{\cos x}+\ln{C}$$

Comment: Exponentiate everything; use $e^{\ln(a)}=a$ for positive $a$.

Comment: You could probably answer you own question once you start listing out what you know and what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is $$U=e^{-\sin(x)+\ln(C\cos(x))}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Even better: $U = Ce^{-\sin x}\cos x $.

Comment: Thank you for your nice hint!